# What is the correct definition of a transparent proxy?

Tags: proxy, transparent-proxy

What is the correct definition of a transparent proxy? I see the term being used for proxies that require no configuration that do not modify  requests and for proxies that do require configuration but do not modify the request. What is the correct definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct definition is that the clients need not to change any settings because the proxy is deployed on the router and hijacks every outbound request of clients.

Comment: Would it be possible for a no configuration proxy to modify outgoing or incoming data? If it modifies the data but is still no configuration, would it still be considered a transparent proxy?

Comment: "transparent" means the client feels nothing about it, like a glass door. In a way, you can interpret it as "invisible", which I believe is more appropriate. I think as long as the client has nothing changed between with and without the setting, it is "transparent" or "invisible".